# Ember multi word model name - The response from a findAll must be an Array, not undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

- My model is 
  var UserLookup = DS.Model.extend({ 'name': DS.attr('string') });
- In My adapter I lookup as follows
  this.store.find('userLookup').then(function(results){ }
- The response from REST API is
  {"userLookups":[{"id":1,"name":"xxx"},{"id":2,"name":"yyyy"}]}

Upon deserialization it fails with error Error: **Assertion Failed: The response from a findAll must be an Array, not undefined**

I made sure the model lookup and the key in JSON response are both camelCased. If I rename the model with a single word, everything works.

Am I missing something in serializer that could cause this error?

Comment: Did you register the model on your application variable, i.e. `App.UserLookup = ...`? Because I don't think it's going to work if you register it as a global.

Comment: I return the model from the router and this works if I rename the model to a single word. The problem arises only in case of models with multi word names.

Comment: Can you put a bin (http://emberjs.jsbin.com/) showing the issue?

Comment: Have you tried returning `{ "user_lookups": [...] }` as JSON, i.e. use snake case instead of camel case?

Comment: Are you using the Rest or ActiveModel serializer? If so, can you try debugging https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/rest_serializer.js#L534 to see what type ED is trying to lookup for your "userLookups" key?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the root key in the API response needs to `user_lookups`, not `userLookups`